# Retrieve users / groups assigned to outlook addin from Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

**Design**

1. Outlook Add-in that shows sales specific information based on the message (content, sender, etc)
2. Daemon that subscribes to new messages for the sales team and processes messages as they come in.  Runs with application authentication

**Scenario**

We are developing a multi-tenant add-in that show sales specific information based on the email they are viewing.  Since the sales team may be a single person, group or multiple people.

**Question**

How would the daemon running as an application use the graph to pull in users assigned to it?

**Office 365 Admin Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need an Azure AD Application registered with Mail.Read persmissions. The add-in would sign in as the user. Then have the add-in subscribe to the users mailbox on the users behalf. The subscription would include the URL of a backend web api that Microsoft Graph subscription service would call.

You would need to register a new Azure AD Application (if you don't have one created already) for the backend web api. Then you would want to grant the correct permissions scopes to it. For your scenario you would require each tenant to admin consent this application, because you would need access to messages in many users mailboxes using application permission Mail.Read. The reason for this is because the webhook does not call your web api with any user token that you could use to then actual fetch the details of the message.

More info on change notifications (webhooks) is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

Comment: Hi Jeremy, 

Thank you for your response.  I have setup an AD application and have both the addin and daemon working currently.  

We need to keep the subscriptions in the service instead of the add-in so they can be processed if the user is not actively using their mailbox.  From my understanding of subscription they need to be renewed and if we are creating them inside the adding they could expire and the daemon would no longer receive new messages as they came in.

Is it possible via graph api to pull in what users / groups have been assigned access to an add-in?

Comment: Is the question "how can I see which users using this specific app?" or "how can I see the subscriptions to this specific object?"